# why is my media query not changing anything?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to apply media queries to my website, however nothing is changing.

I have tried changing the position of my media query in the CSS flow, but no joy.

here is the specific part of the code:

```
.desktop-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.mobile-header {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-header {
    display: none;
}
 .mobile-header {
   display: flex;
   height: 4rem;
   width: auto;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
 }

}
```

I would like to replace the desktop header with a simplified mobile header that just displays images rather than the text. Currently, nothing is changing at all. Everything seems sound in the html, so I can only think I am leaving something out of the CSS?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does adding `!important;` to your `display: none;` do anything? It could just be an issue with specificity if you have other classes assigned etc.

Comment: works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/7ry089me/, you must have other styles or js interfering - please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - often the process of doing so will point you to the code causing the issue

Comment: The code you share here should replicate your existing problem. Otherwise it's impossible ( nearly impossible ) for us to help you solve that problem

Comment: @karl No, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MihaiT As far as I am aware, this is the part of the code that is causing me the problem. would it be helpful if I posted the whole CSS document?

Answer (score 0):

I found nothing wrong with your code. It's absolutely fine! May be there are other conflicting code that bars your code from displaying as you intended.

Here I added some HTML and it's working fine with your code.

```css
.desktop-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.mobile-header {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-header {
    display: flex;
    height: 4rem;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-header">
  <h1>Desktop Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="mobile-header">
  <h1>Mobile Header</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use these media queries and follow at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}